# How to compare dataset in a database in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Please I have populated my database with imported csv data. I want to compare data  by picking two rows each in database. ***Example*** from the json data below, I want to delete by comparing row with *** "id": 1 to "id": 2,*** since the have the same number value and also compare the next two.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "number":30,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "number":30,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "number":10,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "number":60,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  }
```

I need assistance please. Am new to this.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to compare this JSON to the contents in your database? And on what basis so you want to compare?

Comment: Also share any code you have already tried !